# Is possible play hard mode in first playthrough on Mega Man Zero?

Tags: mega-man-zero

I want to play directly on hard mode without play Normal first to unlock it, some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to finish normal mode to unlock hard mode. There is no cheat to unlock it, nor a hack.